# Optimizing Group BY in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, query-optimization

I'm trying to fetch part of a column value into a new column in a view. This is part of the SQL and `METRIC_DETAILS2` subquery is taking huge amount of time. Is there a way I can optimize the query ?

Objective : For a given alert with comma separated field_value as shown below (Original Data), I need to separate the distinct signal metrics and it's type as shown below (Desired Data).

**ABC-High**-Cumulative
**-->** given in bold is signal_metrics, post 2nd hyphen is it's type.

```
Original data:

ALERT_ID       FIELD_VALUE
123            ABC-High-Cumulative, ABC-High-Recent, XYZ-High-Cumulative 
               

Desired Data :

ALERT_ID       SIGNAL_METRIC           SITE_SIGNAL_METRICS_TYPE
123            ABC-High                Recent,Cumulative
123            XYZ-High                Cumulative
```

```
WITH METRIC_DETAILS1 AS
    ( SELECT DISTINCT ALERT_ID, METRICS_WITH_TYPE, SUBSTR(METRICS_WITH_TYPE, 0, INSTR(METRICS_WITH_TYPE, '-', 1, 2)-1) AS SIGNAL_METRIC,
      SUBSTR(METRICS_WITH_TYPE, INSTR(METRICS_WITH_TYPE, '-', 1, 2)+1) AS METRIC_TYPE
      FROM (
      SELECT ALERT_ID, REGEXP_SUBSTR(FIELD_VALUE, '[^,]+', 1, LEVEL) METRICS_WITH_TYPE
      FROM (Select ALERT_ID,FIELD_VALUE
    FROM CM_ALERT_PAYLOAD_DATA
    WHERE FIELD_NAME IN ('Site Signal Metrics Type') )
      CONNECT BY regexp_substr(FIELD_VALUE, '[^,]+', 1, LEVEL) IS NOT NULL)),

    METRIC_DETAILS2 AS
    ( SELECT ALERT_ID, SIGNAL_METRIC, COUNT(*) AS METRIC_COUNT
      FROM METRIC_DETAILS1
      GROUP BY ALERT_ID, SIGNAL_METRIC ) ,

    SIGNAL_METRIC_DETAILS AS
    ( SELECT METRIC_DETAILS2.ALERT_ID,METRIC_DETAILS2.SIGNAL_METRIC,
      CASE
        WHEN METRIC_COUNT=2 THEN 'Recent,Cumulative'
        WHEN METRIC_COUNT=1 THEN METRIC_DETAILS1.METRIC_TYPE
        ELSE NULL
        END AS SITE_SIGNAL_METRICS_TYPE
     FROM METRIC_DETAILS2
     INNER JOIN METRIC_DETAILS1
     ON METRIC_DETAILS1.ALERT_ID=METRIC_DETAILS2.ALERT_ID 
     AND METRIC_DETAILS1.SIGNAL_METRIC=METRIC_DETAILS2.SIGNAL_METRIC
     )

Select * from SIGNAL_METRIC_DETAILS;
```

Please leave your suggestions. Thanks!

Comment: To optimize something you should know the exact operation that takes much time. Blind optimization is a guess with unpredictable result. Please, consider [Realtime monitoring](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/tdppt/monitoring-real-time-database-operations.html#GUID-CE183666-D270-41B1-8410-8CE968168127) to get more details

Comment: @astentx The aggregation in METRIC_DETAILS2 subquery is what's taking time.

Comment: But if you allow more than one row per `alert_id`, which is used for `join` in the `SIGNAL_METRIC_DETAILS `, it will multiply rows of both the tables. Is `SIGNAL_METRIC` missing in join? Do you need this join at all? Because if you need to sum up the rows there's no option to avoid `group by`, but you may avoid unnecessary join and improve overall performance.

Comment: Nice catch, SIGNAL_METRIC was missed in the join condition. I need the join as I need METRIC_TYPE column for my CASE condition value.

Comment: Sample data and desired results would be quite helpful, along with an explanation of what the query is supposed to be doing.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I've updated for better understanding :)

Answer (score 0):

If you need the join only to show the metric type, then you may avoid the join at all: if you have only one type, then any aggregate function will be sufficient, because you'll get this single value. If you need to show all the types as comma-separated list, then use `LISTAGG`

```
WITH METRIC_DETAILS1 AS (
  SELECT
    ALERT_ID, METRICS_WITH_TYPE,
    SUBSTR(METRICS_WITH_TYPE, 0, INSTR(METRICS_WITH_TYPE, '-', 1, 2)-1) AS SIGNAL_METRIC,
    SUBSTR(METRICS_WITH_TYPE, INSTR(METRICS_WITH_TYPE, '-', 1, 2)+1) AS METRIC_TYPE
  FROM (
    SELECT
      ALERT_ID,
      REGEXP_SUBSTR(FIELD_VALUE, '[^,]+', 1, LEVEL) METRICS_WITH_TYPE
    FROM (
      Select ALERT_ID,FIELD_VALUE
      FROM CM_ALERT_PAYLOAD_DATA
      WHERE FIELD_NAME IN ('Site Signal Metrics Type')
    )
    CONNECT BY regexp_substr(FIELD_VALUE, '[^,]+', 1, LEVEL) IS NOT NULL
  )
)

SELECT
  ALERT_ID,
  SIGNAL_METRIC,
  decode(count(*), 2, 'Recent,Cumulative', max(METRIC_TYPE)) AS SITE_SIGNAL_METRICS_TYPE_hardcoded,
  listagg(metric_type, ', ') within group (order by metric_type) as SITE_SIGNAL_METRICS_TYPE_aggregated 
from METRIC_DETAILS1
group by ALERT_ID, SIGNAL_METRIC
```

What about aggregation: there's no any faster way to calculate cumulated value than aggregation. But I am sure that it is not a problem, because it is a very basic operation that exists for years, so DBMS can do it efficiently. The really "slow" parts here is a recursive query (the most slow) and join, because it forces the first `with` to be materialized.

You may *observe* that aggregation is slow because the query with it shows results (in IDE) much slower than without it. But it is a deception: you may get the first few rows very fast, but the overall query execution time will be slow. And actually it may be approximately the same with and without aggregation.

Answer (score 0):

REGEXP_SUBSTR is the operation that was taking huge amount of time. I found an alternative to split delimited column value into rows by using XMLTABLE, getting unbelievable performance now.

```
...
SELECT ALERT_ID,
   METRICS_WITH_TYPE,
   SUBSTR(METRICS_WITH_TYPE, 0, INSTR(METRICS_WITH_TYPE, '-', 1, 2)-1) AS SIGNAL_METRIC,
   SUBSTR(METRICS_WITH_TYPE, INSTR(METRICS_WITH_TYPE, '-', 1, 2)   +1) AS METRIC_TYPE
 FROM
   ( SELECT DISTINCT ALERT_ID,
     METRICS_WITH_TYPE
   FROM METRIC_ALERTS,
     xmltable(('"' || REPLACE(FIELD_VALUE, ',', '","') || '"') 
               passing FIELD_VALUE 
               columns METRICS_WITH_TYPE VARCHAR2(1000) path '.')
   )
...
```

Thanks for your feedback anyway @astentx